# Given just a $4$-distinct-digit number. What are the odds that randomly chosen number has digit $1$ and digit $2$?

Tags: probability, binomial-coefficients, random, decimal-expansion, natural-numbers

> Given just a $4$-distinct-digit number. What are the odds that randomly chosen number has digit $1$ and digit $2$ ?

**My own observation**

With $4$ digits $1, 2, 3, 4$ ; $1$ in $1$

With $5$ digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5$ ; $3$ in $5$

With $6$ digits $1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ ; $6$ in $15$

I guess..

With $9$ digits $1, 2, 3, \cdots, 9$ ; $\binom{7}{2}$ in $\binom{9}{2}$

With $10$ digits $1, 2, 3, \cdots, 9, 0$ ; how ?

*I need to more hints, thank you very much. Also, I want to see a cleverer way(s)..*

Comment: First, a few things should be clarified.  By "4-distinct-digit-number" I assume you are talking about a number uniformly selected from the list 1023,1024,1025,1026, ..., 1203,1204,1205, ..., 9876?  Note that 0 is less common than the others since it is not allowed to be the leading digit.  Second... you say *odds*, but you don't in fact write your answers as odds.  Is this intentional?  Or is probability preferred?  Odds would be written *X against Y* or *X to Y*, not as *x in y*.  Such as a fair coin flip has odds of "1:1" of landing heads or a fair die has odds "1:5" of landing on a six.

Comment: As for your attempts... the first three work, but your attempt for distinct 4-digit numbers without zero appearing as a digit is incorrect.  Where did the binomial coefficient with choose 2 come about?  When zero isn't concerned, making all digits equally likely to occur in each of the positions there are $\binom{9}{4}$ equally likely sets of four digits, $\binom{7}{2}$ of them include both 1 and 2.  (*Perhaps you got the pattern of choose 2 from $\binom{6}{2}=15$ but what you should have seen was $\binom{6}{4}=15$ instead*).  This approach doesn't work if we include zero however.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, about time I meant it.

Comment: So then... allowing for zero, just approach directly with counting.  First, count how many numbers are in that list 1023,1024,1025,...9876 by rule of product: Pick the first number, Pick the second number, pick the third, pick the fourth.  Next,count how many have both 1 and 2 by picking locations of 1 and 2, breaking into cases based on whether the leading digit was used or not.  Then, picking leftmost remaining digit and final remaining digit.

Comment: @JMoravitz I wrote **My own observation** because I can't find a way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are $9*9*8*7$ possible $4$ (distinct)  digit numbers ($9$ choices for 1st spot, etc)

Count number containing both $1$ and $2$:

A) Pick a spot for digit $1$   ($4$ choices)

B) Pick a spot for digit $2$   ($3$ choices)

Now we split up based on whether first spot is used yet. Exactly $6$ of the $12$ choices so far have a digit in the first spot.

C1) If first spot taken, then $8*7$ choices for the two available spots in order. This option occurs in $6$ of the $12$ choices in (A) and (B).

C2) If first spot open, then $7$ choices for first spot, $7$ choices for last open spot. This option occurs in $6$ of the $12$ choices in (A) and (B)

So:  $(6*56 + 6*49) / (9*9*8*7)$

Comment: Using the hypergeometric sum we have $$
H_{4,(1)_{i=1}^{10}}(\{(1,1,x_1,...,x_8)\in\mathbb N_0 ^{10}\mid x_1+...+x_8=2\}) =
\sum_{ x_1+...+x_8=2\\ x_1,...,x_8\in\mathbb N}H_{4,(1)_{i=1}^{10}}(\{(1,1,x_1,...,x_8)\})
=
\sum_{ x_1+...+x_8=2\\ x_1,...,x_8\in\mathbb \{0,1\}}H_{4,(1)_{i=1}^{10}}(\{(1,1,x_1,...,x_8)\})
 = \sum_{ x_1+...+x_8=2\\ x_1,...,x_8\in\mathbb \{0,1\}} \frac 1 {\binom{10}{4}} =\binom{10}{4}^{-1} \sum_{ x_1+...+x_8=2\\ x_1,...,x_8\in\mathbb \{0,1\}} 1  = 
\binom{10}{4}^{-1} \binom{8}{2} \neq (6*56 + 6*49) / (9*9*8*7)
$$ So, either one of us has made a mistake

Comment: @Sudix. Does your method take into account the special status of the digit $0$ in this problem? It looks like your answer is the probability of picking both $1$ and $2$ if you pick $4$ distinct digits from $0$ through $9$ without the restriction on $0$ not being the first digit. My answer $5/36$ is slightly larger than yours $2/15$ due to $0$ occurring less often in mine.

Comment: @Sudix I agree that your answer is the incorrect one (*and unnecessarily complicated, you could have gone straight to $\binom{8}{2}/\binom{10}{4}$ via counting arguments*).  It would have been the correct answer for length four *strings* which allows leading zeroes, but not for four-digit numbers.which does not allow leading zeroes.  The number $0123$ (*i.e. the number $123$*) is considered a three-digit number, not a four-digit number.